# trasform with a regex a string in a html text

Tags: javascript, html, regex, string, tags

How to trasform correctly a string like this:

```
html attr = "value" attr2 = 'UnmatchInSubstrings' some \escapedTag content subtag subcontent /subtag br / /html
```

in:

```
<html attr = "value" attr2 = 'UnmatchInSubstrings'> some escapedTag content <subtag>subcontent</subtag> <br /> </html>
```

Requirements:

1. Does not match tags in substrings (text in "" and '')
2. Use the character \ to escape a tag you want as normal text. The escaped tag losts its slash.
3. Match unclosed tags like br /

I have tried with a regex like the follow, that does not works as excepted:

```
/([^\\]\S+[\s[\"|\']+\s\S[\"|\']+]*)+/g
```

.

*For my attempts, I'm using regex101.com*

Thank you in advance and sorry if it is not well comprehensible :)

Comment: [DON'T try parsing HTML with regexes.](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html). Are you absolutely certain this is how it has to be done? Do you have control over how the string you want to parse, if formatted?

Comment: For those who'd say "it's not HTML he's parsing": Same difference. He s trying to parse something that represents HTML. Same complexity (Or even worse, as there are no `<>`)

Comment: How do you will know that `some` isn't an attribute? Or `br` isn't part of content but a tag? You'll need AI, I think.

Comment: don't worry "dontVoteMeDown", I will check if "some" is a tag after I done the regex with a simple tag list..
guys, what solution you propose ?

Comment: How are you meant to use a HTML parser if it's not valid HTML that he's parsing?

Comment: ManuelDiIorio: Do you have any access to the way the input string is built?
@VasiliSyrakis: That's not what I'm saying.

Comment: @Cerbrus: in what sense ?

Comment: Can you change the way the string is built?
Where is the string even coming from?

Comment: This type of string is a draft. I thought this structure to improve the flexibility of a template engine I made (like Jade). You have carte blanche to improve it.

Comment: Yea, there's the problem.
Just use HTML with placeholders for attributes / content: `<html $attributes>$comeContent<subtag>$subcontent</subtag><br /></html>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you want, you would need to write your own mapper. So in short, you would have a list of `keywords`, such as `html`, `table`, etc through which you would need to match your strings.

Ideally you would also have a stack onto which you push/pop keywords as you find open/close tags. The parser would also need to be intelligent enough to exclude your escape sequences as well as strings within quotation marks, so that you won't end up with `"I know <html>"`.

Comment: I think that char-by-char parsing is the only solution.. just the thing I wanted to avoid (a lot of rows of code)... Thanks anyway

Comment: @ManuelDiIorio: Word by word should be enough I think. Replacing `br /` with `br/` and splitting by space should reduce the complexity as well.